# Regular expression - only include 0 if in 2nd position of x.x.x

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop

I am trying to figure out how to write a regular expression for a string of the format xx.xx.xx (but sometimes the third argument is not included)

For example, the strings could be:

```
12.1
12.1.0
14.5.1
8.2.1
8.2.0
8.2
```

What I want is to throw out the trailing 0 if it's included in the third position (or, alternatively, pad with a 0 if the third argument is missing).

Desired output (from above):

```
12.1
12.1
14.5.1
8.2.1
8.2
8.2
```

Or, if it's easier to pad a zero, the desired output would be:

```
12.1.0
12.1.0
14.5.1
8.2.1
8.2.0
8.2.0
```

Tried (in SQL):

```
SELECT regexp_extract('10.0.0', '^([^.]*.[^.]*.[^.]*[^0])', 0);
SELECT regexp_extract('10.0.0', '^([^.]*.[^.]*.[^.0]*', 0);
SELECT regexp_extract('10.0.0', "([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[1-9]+)");
```

Most of the above just give me the 10.0.0 instead of 10.0, for example.

Comment: Does it need to be a regular expression alone? For this kind of task on the command line I would use `awk`. It looks like you have some specific need for this to work with SQL, though?

Comment: Thanks all for the help so far.  Yeah, it needs to be SQL.  And this will be run against a very large data set in Hadoop, so computational speed is a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('10.0', '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$', '\\0.0');
```

Or maybe use `$0` instead of `\\0` as the full capture group:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('10.0', '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$', '$0.0');
```

The regex `^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$` would only target terms having exactly two (but not three) path components.  In this case, it would append a trailing `.0`

Comment: Thank you!!  Picking this one as it captures what I need and seems to run the fastest in my Hadoop environment.

Answer (score 0):

Padding with a zero is pretty easy:

```
select (case when col not like '%.%.%'
             then concat(col, '.0')
             else col
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

`SELECT regexp_extract('10.0.0', "([0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[1-9]+)?)");`

In your expression above, it will fail to match altogether because of the trailing section .[1-9]+. By adding the parens around this expression, you can annotate it with "?" which matches if it is present once or not present.